# Why does aiohttp behaves synchronously?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I wrote this script to process a few hundred thousand lines with an localhost API, but the code behaves synchronously.

```
  async def process_line_async(session, line):
    async with session.put('http://localhost:8887/load', data=line) as response:
        r = await response.json()
        sys.stdout.write(
            f"some info about the response\n")

  async def looper(lines):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            tasks = []
            for line in lines:
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(process_line_async(session, line))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


 asyncio.run(main(lines))
```

When I test it, or when I modify the process_line_async() function leaving out the request part, with a time.sleep() statement and some arbitrary print, it works but it behaves synchronously

Comment: Do you mean that if you do not leave out the request part and do not add a time.sleep() statement it works as intended?

Comment: Understand the difference between `time.sleep` and `await asyncio.sleep`

Comment: `time.sleep` blocks the event loop.